# Writing JSON data to a file incorrectly

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm reading information from a api which returns text in JSON format. I want to take that text and write it to a file. When I do it writes it with a \ in front of everything looks like this .

```
[{ \"ElementA":\"ValueA" ... }]
```

Here's what I've tried

```
var info = []
request('someApi', function(err, res, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('Error:', err);
  }
  if (res.statusCode != 200) {
    return console.log('Invalid:' + res.statusCode);
  }
  info = JSON.stringify(body);
  fs.writeFile('public/file', info);
});
```

Also the file that I'm trying to write to is .JS if that makes any difference.
My desired output is :

```
 [{ "ElementA": "Value A ...}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the data which you are trying to write is already a well formed JSON, you don't have to `JSON.stringify` it and you can simply write it as it is, like this

```
fs.writeFile('public/file', body, callbackFunction);
```

**Note:** `fs.writeFile` is an async function. You need to pass the callback function as well, which will be invoked when the actual writing is completed.

Comment: You can use fs.writeFileSync is synchronicity is important.